# Python 3.8.5 НЕ ПРАВИЛЬНО РАБОТАЕТ игра

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#камень, ножницы , бумага
#импортируем модуль и заставляем его выбрать одно случайное число (0-2)
    import random
    winner = ' '
    computer_choice = random.randint (0, 2) #0,1,2
#выбраному числу присваиваем значение
    if computer_choice == 0 :
        computer_choice = 'камень'
    elif computer_choice == 1  :
        computer_choice = 'бумага'
    else:
        computer_choice = 'ножницы'
#спрашиваем, что выбрал юзер
    user_choice = input('Камень, ножницы или бумага?  ')
#прописываем возможные исходы( победа пк ) , в остальных случаях будет победа юзера
    if computer_choice == user_choice :
        winner = 'Ничья'
    elif computer_choice ==  'бумага' and user_choice == ' Камень':
        winner = 'Компьютер'
    elif computer_choice == 'Камень' and user_choice == ' ножницы':
        winner = 'Компьютер'
    elif computer_choice == 'бумага' and user_choice == ' бумага':
        winner = 'Компьютер'
    else: winner == 'Пользователь!'
#объявление победителя
    if winner == 'Ничья':
        print('Мы оба выбрали ' + computer_choice + ', играем снова!')
    else:
        print('Я выиграл, я выбрал ' + computer_choice)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: computer_choice = 'камень'   elif computer_choice == 'Камень'    у вас разные камни

Answer (score 1):

```
if computer_choice == 0 :
    computer_choice = 'камень'
                      ^^^^^^^^
...
elif computer_choice ==  'бумага' and user_choice == ' Камень':
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^
    winner = 'Компьютер'
elif computer_choice == 'Камень' and user_choice == ' ножницы':
                                                    ^^^
```

У вас в сравниваемых строках:

- разный регистр, приведите все слова к одному регистру
- лишние пробелы в начале строки, уберите их

И чтобы десять раз не писать одни и те же слова, заведите лучше переменные под эти слова и пишите эти переменные везде. При написании строк легко ошибиться и никто вас не поправит. А если напишете не ту переменную, вылезет ошибка, которую можно будет заметить и понять.

```
rock = 'камень'
paper = 'бумага'

if computer_choice == 0 :
    computer_choice = rock
...
elif computer_choice == paper and user_choice == rock:
...
```

Если сомневаетесь во вводе пользователя - какой там регистр и нет ли пробелов в начале и конце, то приведите его в нужный вид перед тем, как сравнивать:

```
user_choice = user_choice.strip().lower()
```